# Grails error creating remoteFunction

Tags: ajax, function, grails

In one of my views I have added a `remoteFunction` like this:

```
 <select onchange="${remoteFunction(action:'results', controller:'results' )}">
    <option>first</option>
    <option>second</option>
</select>
```

My Controller:

```
class ResultsController {
    def results() {
        render (template="results", bean="resultDiv")
    } 
}
```

I keep getting an error:

```
 Error generating scaffolded view [/patientList/list]: No signature of method: SimpleTemplateScript2.remoteFunction() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) ....
```

What could be wrong? I am really stuck here!

Comment: `template="results"` is a typo? Should be `template:"results", bean: ""`

Comment: And looking at your error, you add this code to a `src/template` right?

Comment: The select code is in another gsp view